# JavaScript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at prac.js:13

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select all the "P" child elements under the "contentWrap" div and change all the "p" elements to the color to red, but I keep on getting this error message. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at prac.js:13"

The JavaScript

```
const wrap = document.getElementsByClassName("contentWrap");
const p = document.getElementsByTagName("P");
const ch = wrap.children;

const select = (e)=>{
    if(e.target.tagName === "P"){
        p.style.color = "red";
    }
}
    for(let i=0; i<ch.length; i++){  //this is line 13 where the error occurs
        select(ch[i]);
    }
```

The HTML

```
<div class="contentWrap center">
        <div class="newRelease"><image class="br2"src="images/thumbnails/battlefieldps4.png"></image>
                    <p class="subTitle sline">New Releases</p>
                        <p class="pContent">Check out the newest releases for each console.</P>
                </div>
                    <div class="preRelease"><image class="br2" src="images/thumbnails/madden.png"></image>
                        <p class="subTitle sline">Pre Orders</p>
                            <p class="pContent">Pre order games, for future release dates in advance.</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="news"><image class="br2" src="images/thumbnails/news.png"></image>
                            <p class="subTitle sline">Gaming News</p>
                                <p class="pContent">Check out the latest buzz & trending topics for all the different consoles.</p>
                        </div>
            </div> <!--end of contentWrap div-->
```

Comment: Maybe using `css` is better option here (instead of js)? `.contentWrap p { color: red}`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the key `children` on the result of `getElementsByClassName` (the variable `wrap`). This value is not a DOM node and does not have a `children` property, so `ch` ends up being `undefined` (hence `undefined.length` throws the error you're seeing). You probably want to get the `children` of one of or all of the elements returned by `getElementsByClassName`. Here is how you would do that:

First:

```
const ch = wrap[0].children;
```

Last:

```
const ch = wrap[wrap.length - 1].children;
```

All (iterate over each element with the class `contentWrap` and do something with its children):

```
for(let contentWrap of wrap) {
  const { children } = contentWrap;
}
```

The third (or whatever index you want) element with the class `contentWrap`:

```
const ch = wrap[2].children;
```

You may want to read [this MDN article on getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).